# How to use implement calendar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter  and struggling to follow the use of external packages. An example is implementing the calendar from https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-rounded-date-picker

My code is shown below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_rounded_date_picker/rounded_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'), // English
      ],
      title: 'Calendar Tester',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Timesheet"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text('JX',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,15,15,5),
                  padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape:BoxShape.circle,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),

                ),
                Text('John X',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70,25,15,5) ,
                  child: Text("MONDAY, 11 JULY 2020",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
//                  child:

                )
                          ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      );

  }
}
```

I simply want to include the calendar in the last container, using the child property that I have currently commented out. The docs for the library say I should just do this:

```
DateTime newDateTime = await showRoundedDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
  lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1),
  borderRadius: 16,
),
```

Where exactly does this go and how do I get to show the calendar? Only interested in getting the calendar to show at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  DateTime dateTime;
  Duration duration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    dateTime = DateTime.now();
    duration = Duration(minutes: 10);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _buildBody() {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Date Time selected",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "$dateTime",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "Duration Selected",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "$duration",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    DateTime newDateTime = await showRoundedDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
                      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1),
                      borderRadius: 2,
                    );
                    if (newDateTime != null) {
                      setState(() => dateTime = newDateTime);
                    }
                  },
                  label: const Text("Material Calendar (Original)"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Rounded Date Picker'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
        child: _buildBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image][image]